# Is $\sup_{{\rm diam}(\Omega)=2,\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2}\mu_1(\Omega)=\infty$?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Denote $\mu_1(\Omega)$ be the first positive Neumann eigenvalue of domain $\Omega$. My question is that:

Is
$$
\sup_{{\rm diam}(\Omega)=2,\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2}\mu_1(\Omega)=\infty?
$$

Under these assumptions, I guess this supremum is $\infty$. But I don't know how to find a "blow up" sequence of such domain. I've proved that if $\mu_1(\Omega_k)\rightarrow\infty$, then the volume of $\Omega_k$ must tend to zero, but I can't go further.

Any help will be appreciated a lot !  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: calculate the Neumann eigenvalues for $(-1,1) \times (-\delta, \delta)$. What happens when you make $\delta $ small?

Comment: Thanks for your answer JackT, but I'm afraid that the first Neumann eigenvalue for your example is $\pi^2/4$.

Comment: @Frankie ah yes you’re right this only works for Dirichlet BCs. sorry about that